# Insert data from pyspark dataframe to another cassandra table using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a **cassandra** table - **test**:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | country | counter |
+====+=========+=========+
|  A |      RU |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  B |      EN |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  C |      IQ |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  D |      RU |       3 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Also I have a table **main** in the same space with column "country_main" and "main_id".
In column main_id I have same ids as in test table, and also I have some unique ids. country_main has empty values and the same as in test. For ex:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
| main_id | country_main |      ...|
+=========+==============+=========+
|  A      |              |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  B      |      EN      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  Y      |      IQ      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
|  Z      |      RU      |      ...|
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

How to insert data from test table to main using pyspark to fill empty values in country_main according to ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having following schema & data:

```
create table test.ct1 (
  id text primary key,
  country text,
  cnt int);

insert into test.ct1(id, country, cnt) values('A', 'RU', 1);
insert into test.ct1(id, country, cnt) values('B', 'EN', 2);
insert into test.ct1(id, country, cnt) values('C', 'IQ', 1);
insert into test.ct1(id, country, cnt) values('D', 'RU', 3);


create table test.ct2 (
  main_id text primary key,
  country_main text,
  cnt int);

insert into test.ct2(main_id, cnt) values('A', 1);
insert into test.ct2(main_id, country_main, cnt) values('B', 'EN', 2);
insert into test.ct2(main_id, country_main, cnt) values('C', 'IQ', 1);
insert into test.ct2(main_id, country_main, cnt) values('D', 'RU', 3);
```

It should be something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

ct1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
   .option("table", "ct1").option("keyspace", "test").load()

ct2 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
  .option("table", "ct2").option("keyspace", "test").load()\
  .where(col("country_main").isNull())

res = ct1.join(ct2, ct1.id == ct2.main_id).select(col("main_id"), 
  col("country").alias("country_main"))
res.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
   .option("table", "ct2").option("keyspace", "test")\
   .mode("append").save()
```

What code does:

1. selects all rows from `ct2` (corresponds to your `main` table) where `country_main` is `null`;
2. performs join with `ct1` (corresponds to your `test` table) to get value of country from it (optimization could be to select only necessary columns from both tables). Also, please note that join is done by Spark, not on Cassandra level - Cassandra-level joins will be supported only in upcoming version of Spark Cassandra Connector (3.0, but alpha versions already published);
3. renames columns to match structure of `ct2` table;
4. write data back.

Result:

```
cqlsh> select * from test.ct2;

 main_id | cnt | country_main
---------+-----+--------------
       C |   1 |           IQ
       B |   2 |           EN
       A |   1 |           RU
       D |   3 |           RU
```

for source data:

```
cqlsh> select * from test.ct2;
main_id | cnt | country_main
---------+-----+--------------                                       
       C |   1 |           IQ                                  
       B |   2 |           EN                                                                                         
       A |   1 |         null                                      
       D |   3 |           RU
```

Comment: I get empty table in res.

Comment: that code was tested... I think that there is something with table structure, etc. Or you have empty string for `country_main` instead of `null` as in my example... Just do `ct2.show()` to check that you selected some data that you want to join with

Comment: Yeah, I found what problem is this. Data in ct1 was not intersected with data in ct2. Thanks!